# Como utilizar o free em uma variável estrutura (lista encadeada)?

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Não consigo utilizar o `free()` em "`struct Lista *proximo`". Segue meu código:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct Lista {
    int num;
    struct Lista *proximo;
}celula;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
//Criar uma função para a inserção de dados na lista

struct Lista *inicio;
struct Lista *proximo_item;
short int resp = 1;
short int cont = 1;

inicio = (struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
if (inicio == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}

proximo_item = inicio;
do {
    printf("Inf. um numero para a lista: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &proximo_item->num);
    printf("Deseja continuar? 1 = Sim | != Nao\n");
    scanf_s("%hi", &resp);
    system("cls");
    if (resp == 1) {
        proximo_item->proximo = (struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
        proximo_item = proximo_item->proximo;
    }
} while (resp == 1);

proximo_item->proximo = NULL;
proximo_item = inicio;
while (proximo_item != NULL){ 
    printf("%dº item da lista: %d\n", cont, proximo_item->num);
    proximo_item = proximo_item->proximo;
    cont++;
}
free(proximo);
free(inicio);
free(proximo_item);
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neste caso o `fre()` não é tão necessário assim porque o programa está encerrando, mas entendo que queira fazer o certo para usar em outro lugares, ainda que este algoritmo seja muito ingênuo para uso em produção. Se você usou o `malloc()` em um laço, o `free()` precisa ser em um laço também. Como não vai usar mais, talvez poderia usar dentro do laço de impressão, vai imprimindo e liberando. Se puder fazer alguma outra coisa depois, então precisa de laço separada. É essencialmente navegar pela lista como já foi feito no código e liberar em vez de alocar, como já foi feito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque isso:

```
free(proximo);
free(inicio);
free(proximo_item);
```

Por isso:

```
while (inicio != NULL) {
    struct Lista *deletando = inicio;
    inicio = inicio->proximo;
    free(deletando);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!